# How to break ties with order function in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame with 2 columns. I have ordered them using `order()` function

```
data<-data[order(data$Mortality),]
head(data)

                       Hospital.Name     Mortality
 FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER                      8.1
 TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER                 8.5
 DETAR HOSPITAL NAVARRO                          8.7
 CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER                8.7
 MISSION REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER                 8.8
 METHODIST HOSPITAL,THE                          8.8
```

3rd and 4th positions are ties (`Mortality` = 8.7 for both). I want to break the tie with alphabetical order in `data$Hospital.Name` so that "CYPRESS FAIRBANKS" is 3rd and "DETAR HOSPITAL" as 4th.

Answer (score 21):

Use `data$Hospital.Name` as second argument in `order`:

```
R> data <- data[order(data$Mortality, data$Hospital.Name), ]
R> data
                     Hospital.Name Mortality
1       FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER       8.1
2  TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER       8.5
4 CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER       8.7
3           DETAR HOSPITAL NAVARRO       8.7
6           METHODIST HOSPITAL,THE       8.8
5  MISSION REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER       8.8
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like i'm taking the same course as the other user.